# How can I add together costs with the same label on a different sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, label

For example - I have a sheet with running Costs of receipts - What I want to create is something that adds the different values of these receipts based on the label - For example

```
RECEIPT 1 - Travel - £8
RECEIPT 2 - Travel - £5
RECEIPT 3 - Props - £5
RECEIPT 4 - Travel - £6
```

So on *Sheet2* I want all `Travel` to be added together, all `Props`, etc. so I can see exactly how much I spent on each one

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you define `label` - also , is RECIPET 1 in Column A, is Travel in Column B and is the price in ColumnC?

Comment: for use with both answers, make a dropdown for the types, otherwise Props, prop, Travels,Travel or other variations will occur which may cause issues splitting things up when summed.,

Answer (score 2):

You can use a PivotTable to sum costs by category.

Assuming your data looks like this:

[image]

Follow these steps:

1. Select your data area.
2. On the `Insert` tab click `PivotTable`, select the `New Worksheet` option and click `OK`.
3. Drag the `Category` field to the `Row Labels` area and the `Amount` field to the `Values` area.

You should see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMIF

```
=SUMIF(B1:B5;"=Travel";C1:C5)
```

Example in E2

[image]

You might want to change semicolon to comma, depending on the language of your excel version

---

Edit: The pivot table example is a more elegant solution and scales better over large amounts of data.